# Detection of sulphide in solution also containing sulphate

Tags: experimental-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, identification

### Question:

> 28. The reagent(s) that can selectively precipitate $\ce{S^2-}$ from a mixture of $\ce{S^2-}$ and $\ce{SO4^2-}$ in aqueous solution is(are):
>
> (A) $\ce{CuCl2}$
>
> (B) $\ce{BaCl2}$
>
> (C) $\ce{Pb(OOCCH3)2}$
>
> (D) $\ce{Na2[Fe(CN)5NO]}$

### Answer:

> **(A) or (A) and (C)**

Why (C) is considered as correct option even though lead sulphide forms black precipitate and lead sulphate forms white precipitate?

Question source: JEE Advance 2016

Comment: This is an ill-posed question. I think A is a better answer. Your concern is right both sulfate and sulfide should ppt in excess of the lead salt.

Comment: Please write the Q in text. Pictures are not recommended.

Comment: You are correct about (C). Both ions form precipitate with lead acetate. However, the question can also be reworded as "What reagent can help distinguish between sulphide salt and sulphate salt?". In such case, sulphate salt does react with BaCl2 to form white BaSO4. In case of sulphide, no ppt. forms. Additionally, the sodium nitroprusside test is actually a selective test for sulphide only,

Comment: No doubt question can be formatted in better way (words) but it is the real question I am concerned of. I just want to know if I am missing something special knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will add one thing that may be the reason behind why (C) is an acceptable answer choice. Yes, both $\ce{PbS}$ and $\ce{PbSO_4}$ are insoluble. However, if you look at the $\ce{K_{sp}}$ for both compounds, $\ce{PbS}$ is about $\pu{3.2 x10^-28}$ while the $\ce{K_{sp}}$ for $\ce{PbSO_4}$ is $\pu{1.3 x 10^-8}$. When you have a mixture of ions, the resulting molecule with the lowest $\ce{K_{sp}}$ will precipitate first, given that the same stoichiometric ratio is the same. In this case, since $\ce{PbS}$ has a lower  $\ce{K_{sp}}$ than $\ce{PbSO_4}$ and that they have the same stoichiometric ratio, $\ce{PbS}$ will precipitate first.

This technique is called fractional precipitation where you separate two ions, in our case $\ce{S^{2-}}$ and $\ce{SO_4^{2-}}$, by precipitating one of the ions selectively through taking advantage of their differing $\ce{K_{sp}}$ values.

This is the likely reason behind why choosing (A) itself is acceptable or choosing (A) and (C) is also acceptable.

Comment: @MLI would also like to add something, since the question feels as if it lies heavily on the qualitative side thus one may or may not observe both precipitates as in qualitative analysis, generally it is not about taking specific concentration of reagent, that is why I think the answer to this question has been given as A $OR$ A and C.

Comment: We can compare $K_{sp}$ values directly only when stoichiometries match, which they do here. Otherwise you could get different results depending on the overall concentration of the solution. IMO the equal stoichiometries should be mentioned in the answer as allowing the solubility products to be compared.